# In Xcode my UIButton is centered, however when I build and run the app it isn't. How do I fix this?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton, ios-simulator

In Xcode my `UIButton` is centered and locked in the right place using the grids but when I run the app I'm building from a tutorial I'm following the button is slightly to the right.

Is there a quick fix for this other than shifting the button to the left in Xcode until it's centered in simulator which is pointless because the guides in Xcode are there to help so I'd like to take advantage of them and not need to do this.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating XCode I realised the issue was that XCode was launching ios simulator for 3.5inch iphone. I changed the device to iphone 4inch retina and this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have unchecked the `use Autolayout` option for your Xib.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if is horizontal centered image, try like this:

[image]

ps: make sure that the parent view of the UIButton is also centered in the screen